# BASH: find the string and print all related comments above

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i'm using the following script to call certain rows from the files:

```
find / -type f -name "*.prop" -exec grep -Fi "$keyword" --color {} +
```

It works cool, but in addition to it i need to print all the comments above this string. All of them start with '#' char.
Eg: using

```
find / -type f -name "*.prop" -exec grep -Fi "*API*" --color {} +
```

returns me just "API.v=2" and "selectAPI=true"

However i'd like to have all the comments above as well:

```
#Explanation
#Use 1 for...
#use 2 for...
API.v=2

#Another usage
selectAPI=true
```

How can i do this?

Comment: You can use `grep -B n` to print `n` lines before the match.  But that may not give you exactly what you want, if the number of comment lines are not fixed.

Comment: You can use `cat -n` to append line No. before lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grep -B 1` which extends for `--before-context=NUM`. From `grep`'s own documentation:

> Print NUM lines of leading context before matching lines. Places a line containing a group separator (--) between contiguous groups of matches. With the -o or --only-matching option, this has no effect and a warning is given.

Your final script will look like this:

```
find / -type f -name "*.prop" -exec grep -B 1 -Fi "$keyword" --color {} +
```

Comment: Does it print the whole comment block before a keyword?

Comment: You can ajust a fixed number of lines that suits your problem. To print exactly the comment block is whole different command because you will need to create a regex to match it and parse in multi-line way

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -ne 'if (/^#/) { push @buffer, $_ }
          else {
              print @buffer, $_ if /API/;
              @buffer = ();
          }' -- file
```